# How to stop handler after certain time period (In my case 30 sec)?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. 
I am using Handler to change images but it should happen only for 30 sec and after that i want to call another activity

My code:

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

final int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d};

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
            i++;
            if(i>imageArray.length-1){
                i= 0;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this,100);
        }
    };
   handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
```

How do I stop this activity and call another activity after 30 sec?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) delay is in milliseconds, if you want to change image every second `handler.postDelayed(this,100);` should be changed to `handler.postDelayed(this,1000);` (1s = 1000ms)

2) stop task:

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
            i++;
            if(i>imageArray.length-1){
                i= 0;
            }
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 30000){
                handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
            } else {
                //TODO start second activity
            }
        }
    };
```

or you can schedule second runnable to stop changing images after 30s and start another activity:

```
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); //stop next runnable execution

            //TODO start second activity
        }
    }, 30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by using Timer.. below code will run the code every 1 second until reach 30 seconds

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int globalTimer = 0;

                // 30 times  30 * 1000 = 30000 == 30 seconds
                int limitTimer = 30;
                int i = 0;

                // create Timer
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        globalTimer++;
                        //run your code
                        imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                        i++;

                        if(i>imageArray.length-1){
                            i= 0;
                        }

                        //check if globalTimer is equal to limitTimer
                        if (globalTimer == limitTimer) {
                            timer.cancel(); // cancel the Timer
                            // jump to another activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Class.this,Name.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }

                }, 0, 1000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.. Getting this error...Please help

Comment: Is it because of not using handler?

Comment: This error occurs when trying to access UI elements from any thread that is not the UI thread.

To access/modify elements from a non-UI-thread, use runOnUIThread.